# How to use a wild card of sorts to select an element's class with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to add a class to an element when you click on a string.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".addIframeNarrow").click(function(){
            var functionObj =  $(".frame");
            var clickObj =  $(".addIframeNarrow");

            if(functionObj.hasClass("frame-narrow"))
            {
                $(functionObj).removeClass("frame-narrow");
            } else
            {
                $(functionObj).addClass(" frame-narrow");
            }

            if (clickObj.hasClass("on"))
            {
                $(clickObj).removeClass("on");
            } else
            {
                $(clickObj).addClass(" on");
            }
        });
    });
```

In this function, .frame either gets the class or the class is removed. I'd like to change .frame to a wild card so that any container with a class that contains "frame" is affected. How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Could you include a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".frame");` => `$("[class*=frame]");`

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

---

[`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) could be used to further clean up your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".addIframeNarrow").click(function () {
        var functionObj = $("[class*=frame]").toggleClass("frame-narrow");
        var clickObj = $(".addIframeNarrow").toggleClass("on");

    });
});
```

`.toggleClass` returns the object, so its usage on the same line does not affect the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
var functionObj =  $("[name*=.frame]");
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/